How to get opening hours in a Telegram business account via bot?
Business accounts have been introduced into TG and one of the features is the ability to indicate “Opening hours”.
I couldn't find a way to get this time in the aiogram bot. If you print information about the user, chat, or generally all incoming data, then there is a business_opening_hours parameter, but it comes up as None.
Is it even possible to get the Opening Hours specified in the profile in the bot?
P.S. Google translate, sorry =)
I tried to output the data received with the message to the console. It also displayed in the middleware all the data arriving before the handler.

Curl https://api.telegram.org/BOT_TOKEN/getChat?chat_id=@YOUR_CHAT_ID.
In the replying JSON there's a business_opening_hours parameter.
P.S: business_opening_hours is a new parameter and in ChatFullInfo which is a new object recently introduced in Telegram so there's a probability that it's not found within common bot libraries

Thank you. So he really gives out information. The author of the aiograms declares support for the latest Bot API, but apparently not completely, because... the same GetChat method returns None in this parameter.
